# How to write an S3 object to a String in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download the content from s3object to a string in the following manner:

```
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(bucketName, key);
S3ObjectInputStream stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
String text = "";
String temp = "";

try {
    while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        text = text+temp;
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    stream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
m_logger.error("Exception while reading the string " + e);
}
```

but while downloading the content, i am getting the following error

```
 Client calculated content hash didn't match hash calculated by Amazon S3.  The data may be corrupt.
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.DigestValidationInputStream.validateMD5Digest(DigestValidationInputStream.java:73)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.DigestValidationInputStream.read(DigestValidationInputStream.java:61)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
```

Comment: The `text = text + temp` line can really slow down as `text` grows in size. Use `StringBuilder`

Comment: `InputStreamReader` has an overloaded method with an extra Charset parameter Now the default Charset encoding of your platform is used - non-portable. Also `readLine` strips the trailing line end character(s). So you have to add them back again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jcabi-s3](http://s3.jcabi.com) (I'm a developer), which does this job for you:

```
Region region = new Region.Simple("key", "secret");
Bucket bucket = region.bucket("my.example.com");
Ocket.Text ocket = new Ocket.Text(bucket.ocket("test.txt"));
String content = ocket.read();
```

Check this blog post: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/26/amazon-s3-java-oop-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me (although I'd put the close statements in a `finally` block, and handle line endings in concatenating the rows of the file in the `text = text + temp` statement).

Looking at the error message, I get the feeling that this is something occurring in the framework. Have you tried to get data from another object? Or to download the object you're trying to read through an alternative means to see that the data isn't corrupted?

Good Luck!